# Windows 10 doesn't sleep - battery is drained

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, power-management

I have Asus UX431FL and almost new Windows 10 installation. At the beginning everything was fine, but after few weeks i see that when notebook goes to sleep (by closing the lid or pressing power button - and leaving lid open), battery is still drained - after one night battery is empty !
(before it worked well, notebook was sleeping and battery was not drained (not drastically).

Where to look for a problem? Software that blocks normal sleep? some **Event Logs** ? how to diagnose the culprit ?

Comment: Reinstall / upgrade the Power Management Driver, restart, reset the Suspend parameters, make sure Sleep is working (everything appears to be off).  If that does not work, consider a defective or old battery and replace that.

Comment: (1) How old is the battery? (2) Check if you have the latest [BIOS version 300](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX431FL/HelpDesk_BIOS/). (3) Does this happen if you boot in Safe mode and let it sleep overnight in this mode?

Comment: Are you sure it is actually going to sleep?  Also.. device drivers can be allowed to wake the machine from a sleep state to "do stuff".. are you sure the machine isn't waking back up after you put it to sleep?  Check the event log for activity during the time that it should have been sleeping.

Comment: for now it looks like faulty 'Modern Standby'  
Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Disconnected
(which is still described as 'Sleep' in menus). sometimes even fans don't stop to spin.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep mode uses some power from the battery to retain data in memory and will always eventually drain a battery. You can get around this by using Hibernate instead when away from the computer for more than a few minutes. Hibernate stores your memory data on the hard disk, and does not use any power. Hibernate is not visible in Windows 10 by default. Enable the option by going to Control Panel > Power Options > "Choose what the power buttons do" and then ticking the box for Hibernate, which will now show up as a shutdown option in the Start Menu. Alternatively you can run *shutdown /h* from the Run window or a command prompt.

Comment: If the Suspend settings are good and the battery is good, you can suspend overnight and still have a strong battery the next day.

Comment: One of my laptops lasts 20 days in sleep..  one of them about two weeks.  Although this is very good advice if he can't solve the problem, it doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: please, read my question. i said it worked correctly before. draining all battery in 8h is not a proper 'sleep' mode

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like the annoying Modern Standby feature that manufacturers are introducing to "improve" our PCs

Windows 10 Event Viewer shows logs about the system entering/exiting that mode in the "System" section. For example, EventID 507 is the one for exiting Modern Standby

One interesting test is to boot a Live Linux system (or even live XP system) and try Suspend there and see how it performs